# Jquery select2 options conflict when more than one select box exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-select2

Okay,

I don't know how to describe the problem correctly.

It's very weird problem.

I've two select boxes. One for countries select. And another for cities.

Now when I use select2 for both. I find options from the first select box included in the second select box.

**HTML code :**

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>`

**My Javascript code :**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("select[name=country]").select2({theme: "classic"});
        $("select[name=city]").select2({theme: "classic"});
    });
```

**UPDATE**

The code for the select boxes to clarify :

```
              <select name="country" class="country form-control" style="width:12%;border:1px solid rgb(169, 169, 169);direction:ltr;">
                        <option value="" selected>Choose country</option>
                        <?php if (isset($countryRow) && !empty($countryRow)) { ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $countryRow['cou_name']; ?>" data-value="<?php echo $countryRow['cou_code']; ?>" id="<?php echo $countryRow['cou_id']; ?>"><?php echo $countryRow['cou_name'] . " ( " . $countryRow['cou_code'] . " ) "; ?></option><?php } else { ?>
                    <?php
                        foreach ($countryArray as $i => $cA) {
                            echo "<option id='" . $cA['cou_id'] . "' data-value='" . $cA['cou_code'] . "' value='" . $cA['cou_name'] . "'>" . $cA['cou_name'] . " ( " . $cA['cou_code'] . " ) </option>";
                        } 
                    }
                    ?>
              </select>
              <div class="input-hidden" style="display:none;"><input type='hidden' name='con_code' value='' /></div>
              <script>$(document).ready(function () {
                $("[name='country']").on("change", function () {
                    "use strict";
                    var countryCode = $("[name='country'] option:selected").attr("data-value"),       
                        htmlCode = "<input type='hidden' name='con_code' value='" + countryCode + "' />";
                    $("#phone").val(countryCode);
                    $(".input-hidden").html(htmlCode);
                }); });
              </script>
              <select name="city" class="form-control" style="width:15%;border:1px solid rgb(169, 169, 169);direction:ltr;">
                    <option value="" class="standardOption" selected>Choose country first</option>
                    <script>$(document).ready(function () {
                        $("[name='country']").on("change", function () {
                            "use strict";
                            if ($("[name='country'] option:selected").val() !== "") { 
                                var countryID = $("[name='country'] option:selected").attr("id");
                                 $.ajax({
                                    url: 'ajax.php',
                                    type: 'POST',
                                    data: {option : countryID},
                                    success: function(data) {
                                        $("[name='city']").html(data);
                                    }
                                });
                            } else {
                                $("[name='city']").html('<option value="" class="standardOption" selected>Choose country first</option>');
                            }
                        }); });
                    </script>
              </select>
```

Thanks In advance

Comment: it works like you can see in [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/43Lhqpze/1/)

Comment: Not working like that + I'm using ajax on my code. Does it effect ?

Comment: Please, could you update the fiddle in order to show us the problem?

Comment: I've updated with the select box code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally Solved.

That conflict was caused by ajax.

The solution was just to add `containerCssClass: "customClass"` for each `select2()`.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.js-example-basic-single').select2();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script></script>
<select name="country" class="js-example-basic-single" style="width:100px;">
        <option value="0">USA</option>
        <option value="1">UK</option>
        <option value="2">India</option>
</select>
<select name="city" class="js-example-basic-single" style="width:100px;">
        <option value="0">Dallas</option>
        <option value="1">London</option>
        <option value="2">New York</option>
</select>
```

Instead of declaring "select2" on select names i.e. country and city, you can give a common class name to all select and then apply "select2" to that class name. It will display options in their particular select box.

Comment: Still Not working.
I'm gonna update the post with more code to clarify.

Comment: @Hema_Elmasry  I have added a code snippet. It's working in it. Make sure you have called both CSS and JS of select2.

Comment: Yes, I've called.
And I've updated the post with select box code

Comment: In your select, add another class for country class="country form-control **js-example-basic-single**" and for city class="form-control **js-example-basic-single**" And then call "select2" referring that class js-example-basic-single.

Comment: So, I've splited and called select2 for the select boxes by name as I though that the problem was because they have the same class

Comment: Try to remove select2 and see if you are getting desired result. Then if still problem exists, then there is not problem with select2. May be some data fetching problem in your AJAX. See Console log errors while running this script.

Comment: So, I've found out that the problem is from select2